# Error in the log file when connecting to the AWS server

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache2, ubuntu-16.04

I am using terraform to create an instance in AWS. I connect very well to the server, but the log file has the following errors.

```
[Tue Oct 23 18:49:33.725989 2018] [suexec:notice] [pid 11845] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Oct 23 18:49:33.737687 2018] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 11845] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Tue Oct 23 18:49:33.737724 2018] [http2:warn] [pid 11845] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[Tue Oct 23 18:49:33.737728 2018] [http2:warn] [pid 11845] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[Tue Oct 23 18:49:33.742054 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11845] AH00163: Apache/2.4.34 () configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Oct 23 18:49:33.742072 2018] [core:notice] [pid 11845] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

Please sorry if my question is not clear. My main concern here is how to change the mpm default `prefork` to something like `event` or `work`. When I run the command `/usr/sbin/httpd -V`, I noticed that prefork is loaded by default. How can I change this?

Answer (score 1):

These are **Apache httpd** log messages. And they are not even errors, just notices. Don't worry about them or configure the appropriate Apache modules (mod_ssl, etc).

Good place to start: http://httpd.apache.org/

Comment: how to change the mpm default prefork to something like `event` or `work`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, even if this is warning you way want to pay attention to these messages :

`[Tue Oct 23 18:49:33.737724 2018] [http2:warn] [pid 11845] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.`

They are saying you that your linux distro has installed the more compatible MPM (see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mpm.html) which turns to be prefork.

If you don't run anything that is not thread safe (PHP as an apache native module is often the one that can stuck you on prefork MPM) you might want to swicth to another MPM like 'events' to be fully http2 compliant.

`apt-get install apache2-mpm-event` on a Debian based system for exemple